# Normalize in Adaboost without numerical error - Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, normalization

I'm implementing [AdaBoost](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~bbabenko/data/boosting_note.pdf) on Matlab. This algorithm requires that in every iteration the weights of each data point in the training set sum up to one.

If I simply use the following normalization `v = v / sum(v)` I get a vector whose 1-norm is 1 except some numerical error which later leads to the failure of the algorithm.

Is there a matlab function for normalizing a vector so that it's 1-norm is `EXACTLY` 1?

Comment: How would that lead to a failure of algorithm? I am using AdaBoost with the same normalization and its quite ok

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want identical values to be normalised with the same factor, this is not possible. Simple counter example:

```
v=ones(21,1);
v = v / sum(v);
sum(v)-1
```

One common way to deal with it, is enforce values sum(v)>=1 or sum(v)<=1 if your algorithm can deal with a derivation to one side:

```
if sum(v)>1
   v=v-eps(v)
end
```

Alternatively you can try using `vpa`, but this will drastically increase your computation time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Considering I'll need to do this thing only once for T iterations (T can vary up to 1000 though) what is your advice?

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about the algorithm or your code to give any meaningful advice.

Comment: As far as my knowledge on Adaboost is concerned, that numerical error won't make any difference and it is better not to invest time on it.